# Should I be using the django.contrib.auth.models User model? Or is it better to create my own User model?

Tags: django

I'm still a beginner, and for some reason using a built in model such as User seems bugs me a bit. Should I create my own User model to become a more independent programmer, or will the User model do just as fine if not better for my project? Please tell me about the pros and cons about the User model. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: IMHO, use built-in User model. If you wish to modify the model, extend the model

Answer (score -1, accepted):

it bugged me a bit too and now I use node, though **Django** is great for getting started with conventional concepts you'll keep running into over and over. For example, If you use the `User` module, you get authentication and admin panel with not too much more work. The downside is you'll feel a bit like an outsider in your own code. Modifying a built in model is weird, especially when so many other Django components depend on so many attributes.

If you're weighing your options, consider how much you need the free admin and auth. My personal recommendation is to build your own User model and implement the Django-specific attributes yourself.